# Python script - mute system sounds and disable notifications

Tags: python-3.x, windows, macos, pyqt5, video-player

I have a python video player script.
When I play the movie I'd like to mute all system sounds and disable all system notifications (like updates or messages or something) or putting them in the background while video is playing.

I didn't find any solution how to solve this on MacOS and Windows. I hope somebody can help me here!

Comment: There is no cross platform solution, as each OS has different ways to manage volume control. And I'm not even sure macOS allows that from normal applications (maybe through applescript?). For windows, see [pycaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw).

Comment: you can use the `os` module to determine the operating system...

Answer (score 0):

the starting point is to determine the operating system, which would be somethings like this using the `os` module:

```py
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    print("Windows")
elif os.name == 'posix':
    print("Linux")
elif os.uname()[0] == 'Darwin': 
    print("macOS")
else:
    print("Unknown OS")
```

From this point you can do whatever you like within the respective operating system. Left as an exercise for the OP.